# Catch element by class using index or eq in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML code:

```
<table border='1' cellpadding='5'> 
    <tr>
        <td class="order"><a href="#">two</a></td>
        <td>demo</td>
        <td>last</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>two</td>
        <td class="order"><a href="#">three two</a></td>
        <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>two</td>
        <td class="order"><a href="#">five two</a></td>
        <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>five</td>
        <td>quick</td>
        <td class="order"><a href="#">nine</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.order').click(function(){
var index = $(this).index();
    var text = $(".order:eq(index-1)").text();
    alert(text);
});
```

On clicking any `order` class I want to get previous or next element with same `order` class. What iswrong with my code.

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Iftakharul_alam/qgqxauvh/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index` is a variable so you have to add it to the string in jQuery like:

```
$(".order").click(function() {
    var index = $(".order").index(this);
    var text = $(".order:eq("+(index-1)+")").text();
    alert(text);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qgqxauvh/2/)

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with that code:

1. First, that form of [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index) will tell you the index of the element relative to its siblings, not relative to other elements with the same class. So with your HTML, it'll always be 1 because all of your `.order` elements are the second child in their parent.
2. The second thing is that this line:

   ```
   var text = $(".order:eq(index-1)").text();
   ```

   ...uses `index` **literally**, it doesn't swap in the value of your `index` variable.

You're on the right track with `index`, though, you just use [a different form of it](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element):

```
var orders = $(".order");
var index = orders.index(this);
```

Then rather than build a selector that jQuery can't hand off to the browser (because it uses a jQuery-specific `:eq` selector), use the [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) *function*:

```
var text = orders.eq(index - 1).text();
```

But you'll want to handle the case where there *is* no previous element as well, perhaps:

```
var text = index > 0 ? orders.eq(index - 1).text() : "default text";
```

Live example:

```js
$('.order').click(function(){
    var orders = $(".order");
    var index = orders.index(this);
    var text = index > 0 ? orders.eq(index - 1).text() : "default text";
    alert(text);
    return false;
});
```

```html
<table border='1' cellpadding='5'> 
    <tr>
        <td class="order"><a href="#">two</a></td>
        <td>demo</td>
        <td>last</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>two</td>
        <td class="order"><a href="#">three two</a></td>
        <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>two</td>
        <td class="order"><a href="#">five two</a></td>
        <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>five</td>
        <td>quick</td>
        <td class="order"><a href="#">nine</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the index based on the collection set

```
var $orders = $('.order').click(function () {
    var index = $orders.index(this);
    if (index > 0) {
        var text = $orders.eq(index - 1).text();
        alert(text);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bw7xet8b/)